# Finding file knowing only file name, not path - Python

Tags: python, file, path

Is there any method for finding file knowing only file name (ONLY file name without file path)  e.g. "20.10.2021.txt" and copy this file in some other directory???

Comment: What you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know exactly the path, there could be several candidates matching the filename :

```py
import pathlib
files_candidates = list(pathlib.Path(your_dir).glob("**/20.10.2021.txt"))
```

Then, use `shutil.copy` method to copy your file in other directory; let's assume it's the first candidate:

```py
import shutil
shutil.copy(files_candidates[0], destination)
```